# Slow Wifi, want to make fix permanent

Tags: release-juno, wifi

After installing Elementary OS, there was no wifi adapter. I followed [these instructions](https://elementary-os-solutions.blogspot.com/2019/01/wifi-not-working-in-elementary-os-juno.html) and it worked, however, my wifi was extremely slow compared to other devices using the same network.

The fix for this problem was:

```
 sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2
```

After running that command, my wifi becomes normal again, however, the fix is not permanent. Every time I boot up the PC, I need to run that command to not have slow wifi. I would like to make this solution permanent.

Comment: Try `echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl-ant-sel.conf`